# How do I create a web app that is installable on homescreen for both ios and android

Tags: android, ios, web-applications

I am aware that you can add meta tags to an html page to tell ios and android that they are can be installed on the homescreen.  For Android/Chrome google tells us to do it like so.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
   <head>
     <title>Awesome app </title>
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
     <meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
     <link rel="icon" sizes="196x196" href="/icon.png">
   </head>
   <body></body>
</html>
```

For IOS, it appears you need to just add

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
```

But google has warnings on the same page that says how to do it for android that it will stop supporting this soon.

I already have a desktop only version of a single page web app to support a competition for picking the American Football results in a season.  I created this for a community web site that I run and I would like to convert it to run on mobile devices (this is a complete rewrite to break it into smaller individual screens).  However the community will have a wide variety of devices - from phones to tablets - and indeed still desktops, and if possible I would like to support all of them with a single page.

I would like that phone and tablet users could either install to the homescreen, or include a toggle fullscreen button if they haven't, desktop users may use the toggle fullscreen button, but it probably doesn't matter as much as they normally have plenty of screen space.

All the guides I have seen give advice peacemeal for each device.  Not one that I have seen describes how I might combine all these techniques together for a single app.

Is it possible, and if so how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is working for us on iOS 5,6,7,8 and Android 4.0+

```
<!-- Enable the homescreen app on mobile devices -->
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

<!-- Enable the App Icon -->
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" sizes="196x196" href="images/AppIcon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="images/AppIcon.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="http://ourURL/images/iPhoneStartup.png">

<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no, height=device-height, width=device-width" />
```